# Invoke a callback with an unknown number of parameters

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript to invoke a callback with an unknown number of parameters?

For example, if this was our invoking method:

```
function invokeCallback(callback, params) {
    return callback.invoke(params);
}
```

And if these were our example callback methods:

```
function action() {
    doSomeAction();
}

function greet(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}

function nameage(name, age) {
    var msg = 'My name is ' + name + ' and my age is ' + age;
    console.log(msg);
}
```

And if we could then easily call them like so:

```
invokeCallback(action);
invokeCallback(greet, 'Hello!');
invokeCallback(nameage, 'Bob', 20);
```

Then it would be great.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but the answer to my question is not contained within that question. Please revise your comment.

Comment: Good call. Sometimes questions may appear to match others, but the outcomes are often different. In this case, the answer was quite simple, and for the sake of the community, we should have questions like this for people who only need simple answers. Should I require more information, I will be sure to follow your link. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already mentioned in the other answers, [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) are the two methods you want to look at. They differ slightly in how they operate - apply takes arguments as a single array, whilst call takes them as individual parameters.

A related concept you might wish to explore where this technique is used is [currying](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html).

With regard to your example, you should look at removing the `params` argument from your function definition and eliminating the opening argument which is the callback function itself:

```
function invokeCallback(callback) {
    var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return callback.apply(this, params);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible. The key function is [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which calls a function while supplying a context and parameters. The parameters are given as an array. (In this way it differs from [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), where the parameters are given explicitly.)

So let's look at your function signature:

```
function invokeCallback(callback, params) {
```

We could do this very simply:

```
function invokeCallback(callback, params) {
    return callback.apply(null, params);
}
```

(The first argument is the *context* for the function, i.e. the value of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) within it. Since we don't want to specify anything particular, we use `null`.)

However, the way you call your function is slightly different:

```
invokeCallback(nameage, 'Bob', 20);
```

Do you see the difference? Here, the parameters are given explicitly, not as an array. We therefore need to handle it slightly differently. Within a function, the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object contains the arguments supplied to the function. In the above case, it would contain three: `nameage`, `'Bob'`, and `20`. We want to call `nameage` with the parameters `'Bob'` and `20`.

The `arguments` object looks like an array, but it isn't one. We therefore have to use a slightly complex call to the [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function to get the values out:

```
var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); // get all arguments after the first one
```

So our function would look like this:

```
function invokeCallback(callback) {
    var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); // get all arguments after the first one

    return callback.apply(null, params);
}
```

Comment: Answered the question perfectly, and concisely unlike the answers on the apparent duplicate question. Thanks @lonesomeday!

Answer (score 3):

callback.apply or callback.call

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Your callback would then look like:

```
function invokeCallback(callback, params) {
    return callback.apply(this,params);
}
```